# Accepted answer reward +15 awarded twice!

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

Today a strange thing happened.  I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689634/do-i-need-to-perform-a-commit-after-a-rebase/2689720#2689720) and it was considered good enough to be accepted.  Way too good.  Because its acceptance gave me +30 rep!

[image]
<sub>(source: [coldattic.info](http://coldattic.info/pic/699826323441.png))</sub>

Here's an excerpt from audit page:

```
 2   2681595 (10)
 1   2689720 (15)
 1   2689720 (15)
 2   2691220 (10)
```

Is it a bug, a small reward for my commitment, or I'm just the Chosen One?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Say that's a hot-looking cat up there.

Comment: Looks like a bug... feels like a feature!

Comment: Your midichlorians are off the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed - thanks (or condolences :)

Comment: Yeah, fixed :-(.  By the way, I'm curious, what was it?

Comment: (by "what was it?" I don't mean "how can I do it again, but without notifying anyone this time?")

Comment: What was the bug?

Comment: It had to do with two requests happening at the **same** instant; our locks didn't catch them and two votes were submitted.

Comment: @Jarrod - still busted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47964/bug-awarded-double-rep-for-accepted-answer

Comment: And again, @Jarrod: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/answer-accepted-twice ;-)