# Please fix the Q/A pairs that have an accept vote but don't show a green tick

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

A couple of weeks ago I answered [Data Dump Accepted Answer with wrong ParentId](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141101/data-dump-accepted-answer-with-wrong-parentid/299488#299488) and that revealed some corner cases where questions had multiple accepted answers and questions that didn't show an accepted answer but one of their answers had an accept vote.

Some of these case could be rectified by [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896240/timeline) and [undeleting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896471/timeline) an answer but the cases I present here [can't be fixed by the delete/undelete trick](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=38629242#38629242).

Here is a single [SEDE query for Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/732310) and as far as I can tell it isn't present on other sites, based on [this multi site query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/732320)

Example cases:

- [In Lisp (Clojure, Emacs Lisp), what is the difference between list and quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896542/in-lisp-clojure-emacs-lisp-what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-quote) ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896580/timeline))
- [Large table querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896564/large-table-querying) ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896583/timeline))

Why is this important to be fixed? The answer is lacking the green accept mark so there is no visual indication for the future visitor that this answer indeed helped the OP while the event history tells us otherwise. Also those answers don't stick to the top in cases where there are multiple answers.

Please rectify these data errors so the answers that have an accept vote indeed show up as such and the answers that shouldn't have an accept mark doesn't.

Comment: Oh, that could be the explanation @Tom because unaccepts are not in a visible timeline for us mortals. I'll accept that as an answer but the mods that helped me with this either didn't notice or didn't mention it so I assume that is not the case.

Comment: I already deleted that comment :P. The "unaccept" isn't in the timeline, but the "accept" is gone as well (#), so that shouldn't be the solution here. It still looks like the answers should have the green ticks. (#) I've searched on MSO for questions regarding sudden unaccepts and neither of these answers I had checked had an "accept" in their history, so I assume it will be removed during unaccept.

Comment: @Tom as it is a bit of a corner case it helps if the different lines of reasoning and causes are captured so don't worry about it too much.